# Custom Control not Displaying When Adding an External ActionScript File

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, flash-cs5

I am having an issue where I have created a Custom Control and when I add it in a FLA file, it displays as I expect.  When I add an ActionScript (AS) file to my custom control, reload the component list and add the custom control again, it no longer displays the custom control in my FLA file.

Here is what I did (maybe I did something wrong here?):

1. Created a new FLA file and called it Control1.fla
2. Created a rectangle on the stage and right clicked it and selected "Convert to Symbol".
3. I gave it a name of Control1 and clicked OK.
4. Then I right clicked on the control in the Library and selected "Component Definition".
5. I gave it a class name of Control1 and checked the "Display in Components panel" checkbox.
6. I then double clicked the Control1 icon in the Library to open it and simply added a line.
7. Right click Control1 in the Library and select "Export SWC File..." and gave it a name of Control1.swc
8. Then I created a new FLA file and called it Tester.fla
9. I refreshed the Component list (using the little drop down to the right of the Components list label).
10. I dropped the Control1 control onto the stage and I see my control with the line I drew earlier in it.
11. I run the application and I see the control as I would expect.
12. Now I go back to the Control1.fla file and select File / New and select "ActionScript 3.0 Class" file and enter Control1 as the class name.  Change the code to be this:

package
{

```
import flash.display.MovieClip;

public class Control1 extends MovieClip {

    public function Control1() {
        // constructor code
    }

}
```

}

1. I save this AS file as Control1.as
2. I go back to the Control1.fla file and right click on the Control1 icon in the Library list and select "Export SWC File...".
3. I then go back to the Tester.fla file and delete the Control1 object I had on the stage.
4. I refresh the Component list as I did in step 9.
5. I drag the Control1 component onto the stage and select "Replace existing component" in the prompt that appears and I now see my custom control on the stage.
6. However, when I run the application now, I do not see my custom control - I only see a blank white stage.

I am pretty sure I am missing a step or something like that - I am just starting to learn Flash & AS3 and I followed a tutorial on this, but I am running into this problem!

Any help would be greatly appreciated!
Thanks!

Comment: Try restarting flash instead of refreshing the list. flash used to have issues with that. At least that's what I ran into when I developed a component a long time ago.

Comment: Hi - I tried restarting flash as well when I read something about that issue in CS3 - same result unfortunately.  I am using Flash Professional CS5.5.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've never made a custom SWC component but the process you are following is a lot like making a custom FLA component. The step that seems to be missing is saving the file into the config/components folder. Here is the path for that. 
C:\Program Files (x86)\Adobe\Adobe Flash CS4\Common\Configuration\Components
Then restart flash. FLA's also require you to make a shim, which is just a compiled clip that contains your compiled code that you just insert into your the component in your library. I'm not sure if SWC components require that. Here is a link about shims and fla components just in case you need it or decide to switch.

http://www.flexiblefactory.co.uk/flexible/?p=16

http://redbjarne.wordpress.com/actionscript-3-0-custom-components-from-hell/

This one helped me the most but it's not perfect and watch his phrasing. it can be tricky.

Comment: Hi James - I was saving the SWC file to the Components folder, I just didn't mention that in my steps - Sorry about that!  I'll take a look at the links and see if they help.  Thanks!

Comment: Sorry I wasn't more help, I've never used swc's. If you switch to FLA components and need help let me know. I know a little more about those.

Comment: I switched to using FLA's as suggested and got it working without any issues!  Thanks for the suggestion James.